# Как сделать сортировку от большего к меньшему

Tags: javascript, php

Столкнулся с таким вопросом, как сделать сортировку отбольшего к меньшему.

Например
У меня есть вывод числа

```
<div class="coins">
 <div class="cont-im-tx">
  <div class="cont-name-coins">
   <span class="gl-text-coins">Баланс 1</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cont-balance-coins">
  <span class="gl-text-coins"><?php echo $balance1 ?></span>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="coins">
 <div class="cont-im-tx">
  <div class="cont-name-coins">
   <span class="gl-text-coins">Баланс 2</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="cont-balance-coins">
  <span class="gl-text-coins"><?php echo $balance2 ?></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Я понимаю что этот порядок прописан в HTML и мне показывает порядок так как я его написал изначально, но как можно сделать например если баланс 2 больше чем баланс 1 то данная строка показывалась на первом месте если баланс 3 больше чем баланс 2 то выводим баланс 3 на первое место а баланс 2 на второе и тд. То есть список вывода балансов начинался с большего к меньшему.

Рассмотрю все возможные варианты, буду рад вашей помощи.

Comment: А что конкретно пишется вместо  `<?php echo $balance1/2 ?>`?

Comment: Например <?php echo $balance1 ?> выводит значение 55 а <?php echo $balance1 ?> выводит значение 178

Comment: (PHP) - Все ваши `$balance` положите в массив. Отсортируйте, а далее циклом рисуйте HTML. Можно конечно и на JS замутить перестановку DOM элементов, но это будет не правильно